# Thinking Sphinx search_for_ids performance in large data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

User index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, with: :active_record
  ...
  has :group_id
end
```

I want to get all users who belong to the group id : 450. There are about 25000 users under that group.

When I do,

```
User.search_for_ids({:page=>1, :per_page=>1000000, :with=>{:group_id => 450}})
```

It takes about 4 seconds to return the 25000 ids.

Is there anything I am missing or anything I can do better to fetch results faster?

Edit:

References: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/15/sphinx-search-performance-optimization-attribute-based-filtering/

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not sure how well Sphinx performs with such large page sizes... but why not make that query directly from your database instead?

```
User.where(:group_id => 450).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks pat! My scenario here is - I have search option as well here - `User.search_for_ids(search_string, {:page=>1, :per_page=>1000000, :with=>{:group_id => 450}})`. I am fetching the records through sphinx with search_string and then performing filter by ruby on top of the result and then paginating and displaying 100 per page. So in order to apply filter in step 2, i had to fetch all results.

Comment: Is there any way that Ruby filter could be done by Sphinx instead? Care to edit the question and add some details about that? :)

Comment: Definitely Pat! It is a complex filtering based on multiple values. I will definitely check if i can move that filters to sphinx. And can you point me to some link that can help me understand why search is slow for 25K records per page?

Comment: Why? That is a *lot* of data to process. Sphinx has to run the query - get all the documents matching - then filter it to remove any that dont match the query. Then it as to encode the data to send back to the client, finally the client has to then decode all the data again. You might get some benefit by encoding the filter as part of the search string (using fake keywords) rather than attributes. Keeps everything together, rather than a multi-phase search. Also the query will be slightly slowed down by the really large max_matches you must have. Move all teh filtering to sphinx, so can page.

Comment: Thanks very much @barryhunter and @pat! I am facing problems with sort option now. I got objects filtered and sorted by ruby. Now I do, `User.search_for_ids(search_string, {:page=>1, :per_page=>1000000, :with=>{:group_id => 450, :sphinx_internal_id => user_ids}})` Is there a way I can preserve the order of user_ids that I pass to sphinx_internal_id? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: `:order => :sphinx_internal_id`? Or does the order of what's in `user_ids` matter and isn't ASC/DESC?

Comment: Yes Pat. you are right. The order of ids in user_ids matters and is not ASC/DESC. user_ids can be [4, 1, 3]. So `:order => :sphinx_internal_id` gives me results in ASC/DESC which is [4, 3, 1] or [1, 3, 4]

Comment: How is that order determined?

Comment: Is there a way for us Pat to get results in order of `user_ids`?

Comment: @pat I tried with `:sql => {:order => "field(id,#{user_ids.join(',')})"}` but that does not give me result as expected. please correct me if i am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: SPhinx doesnt have a FIELD(..) function. MIght be able to make one via the UDF feature, dont know how easy it would be. If the list of user_id's is modest, could emulate FIELD() using a series of nested IF(..) functions, but kinda uggly.

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter! `field()` is a MYSQL function that I used here to sort based on given order of IDs. `SELECT id from users WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY field(id,1,3,2);` so I am passing this as an SQL ORDER. There was a bug in sql: order that Pat fixed it. I works fine now. But I am facing problem with order of pagination along with sort. Now it applies sort after pagination. But i need pagination to happen after sort.

Comment: because pagination happens in sphinx, you need the sorting to happen in sphinx too. I assumed that order was passed though to sphinx. So you need to figure out how to get sphinx to order them. As noted sphinx doesnt have a FIELD(..) function you can use, so have to emulate it.